# Why doesn't the value of my dictionary update after 2nd input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary with the colour of cars as keys and the amount they are being input as the value, such that if "red" is input twice, the outcome would be "red cars: 2". However, after if I input a colour more than twice, it won't update.

```
cars = {}
i = input("Cars: ")
value = 1
while i:
    if i not in cars:
        cars[i] = value
    elif i in cars:
        cars[i] = value + 1
    i = input("Cars: ")
for i,value in sorted(cars.items()):
    print(i + " cars: " + str(value))
```

If I input, i.e., white 3 times, I get: `white cars: 2`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of ``cars[i] = value + 1`` you want ``cars[i] += 1`` (because ``value`` is never assigned a different value in the while loop, it's hard-coded as 1, and ``1 + 1`` is always ``2``).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace cars[i] = value + 1 with cars[i] += 1

Comment: Damn, thank you so much! I'd have sworn I had tried that before and it gave me an error. I bet I was doing it wrong...